# SSIS Source Component and Commas in the data of a csv file

Tags: ssis

[image]

Hi, I am trying to use the SSIS Source Component to move data into the next component HOWEVER as you can see below there are columns in my cvs source file. I need to use an SSIS Component to scrub my data and replace ONLY the comma in the data with a space (but not touch the delimiters). The data file is actual the end of an ADF Pipeline activity but I don't know how to remove these indata commas in ADF either.

Anyone with any idea how to do that?
Thanks!!
Mike

Comment: What is the actual format of your CSV? Open it with Notepad and find a row with `PSB Bldg K101` and use the `edit` link to patch that on in.

Comment: Thanks, this is an automated system where there can't be any manual intervention, thus I need to use an SSIS Component to do this before I use the Derived Column Transform...Thanks!

Comment: Understood, but the question is "what is the actual format of your CSV?

Comment: it's a comma delimited file

Comment: Right, that's in the name. But what is the format? Is there a reason you cannot supply an answer to your question? We see a screenshot of Excel. Excel takes great liberties with source files to make them presentable for the user but those same liberties are not available to tooling like SSIS. Your solution could be a trivial call to a `REPLACE`. It might be much more complex but without knowing what CSV dialect I'm dealing with, I am hesitant to suggest a solution. [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), while it sounds a standard has wildly different implementations in the wild